# Trying to send data through ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to create some code that checks if a username is taken. I'm kind of half there and having trouble. I'm new to it and trying to learn how to do it & the code will be messy.

the jquery:

```
$('#signusername').keyup(function()
        {       
        var username=$('#signusername').val();         
        if(username != ''){

            $.post('username_check.php', {signusername :username}, function(result)

            {
                    if(result==''){
                        $('.error').text('Avaliable');
                        } else{
                        $('.error').text('Taken');
            }
            }
            );
        }else{
        $('.error').text('???');//this is the the only thing that outputs correctly

        }
```

the php:

```
function checkUsername($signusername, $conn) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info where username= '".$signusername."'");
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $signusername);
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                   return TRUE;
                }
                };


if(isset($_POST['signusername']) && !empty($_POST['signusername'])){
    $signusername= $_POST['signusername'];
    checkUsername($signusername, $conn);
    $result='';
    if(checkUsername($signusername, $conn) == TRUE){
    $result='';
    }else{
    $result='';
}
echo $result;
};
```

I use the same code to check if the username is taken when the form is submitted so I don't think that is the problem. I assume I'm doing something wrong with moving the username variable across? Hope you can help.

Comment: why you calling two times checkUsername($signusername, $conn)?

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?  What indication do you have that there's a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console  for syntex error `};` remove semicolon after `}`

Also remove function calling two time and you sending result blank in both condition so send some response back to ajax in also fail condition

```
if(isset($_POST['signusername']) && !empty($_POST['signusername'])){
    $signusername= $_POST['signusername'];
    $result='';
    if(checkUsername($signusername, $conn) == TRUE){
    $result='user found';  
    }else{
    $result='user not found';
    }
   echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Sigh, I'm such a retard. I wasn't directed it to the username_check.php properly. It was in the js folder but I can't seem to direct js/username_check.php. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
function checkUsername($signusername, $conn) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info where username= '".$signusername."'");
               $stmt->bindParam(1, $signusername);
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                   return TRUE;
                }
return false;
                };


if(isset($_POST['signusername']) && !empty($_POST['signusername'])){
    $signusername= $_POST['signusername'];
    $result = checkUsername($signusername, $conn);
    if($result != TRUE){
       $result='';
    }else{
}
echo $result;
};
```